# Force Selection of New from List of Content Types Only - Disable Click of New button and make it work like dropdown

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, content-type

The New button in the menu bar for a list/document will automatically create the number 1 or default Content Type entry. I would like to disable this and have only the drop down menu in New work which forces the selection of the New entry from Content Types (i.e. I do not want to have a default)

The user wants the new button to act like the drop down arrow and present a selection of all visible content types forcing the user to make a selection from the choices presented.

How to achieve this with SharePoint 2010 using Designer only?